# The video sound starts without starting the video

Tags: html5-video

I am struggling with my video.
The sound starts when I open the page, and without even starting the video.
And on the page, the video only shows as an icon, it can't be started, stopped or mutant....
I don't have any js code for it, so it is nothing that says it shall start....

```
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="images/4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Comment: Try to use a standard mp4 video from the Internet. I think the encoding is the culprit

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
I tried with this code:
    <iframe width="420" height="315"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZb_czxZgFo">
    </iframe>
and the original videos sound comes still up in the background..... It does not get linkt to ennywhere.....I have checked all my code, and I can't figure out how this is possible.